# Do I have reinstall client apps when domain changed?

Tags: networking, active-directory, user-management

Admin we hired gave a wrong domain name (windows network) and going to change it in a few days. He told us he will have to create users list from the scratch.

Do users will have to reinstall client apps they have installed at their workstations at present? 
I mean, if there is a transition "OldDomain/User1" -> "NewDomain/User1" will folders and registry settings stay appropriate in windows?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is a question for your administrator, because the answer depends on exactly what they've done wrong, how they're fixing it (sounds like they're creating a new domain rather than renaming the old one, so why is that?) and how the applications are currently installed.

Having said that, I'll try and give you something useful:

> Admin we hired gave a wrong domain
>   name (windows network) and going to
>   change it in a few days. He told us he
>   will have to create users list from
>   the scratch.

The question here is how are they going to fix it. It's sometimes possible to [rename a domain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208%28WS.10%29.aspx) (which obviously means you don't need to re-create user accounts), so my first question is why are they not doing that?  There are perfectly valid reasons for not doing so, so this doesn't mean they're doing something wrong, but if I had an AD domain in production and the name was the only thing wrong I'd look to rename first before I looked to destroy and re-create.

Next question is what's going to happen to the accounts that are being "created from scratch". If the accounts are just going to be destroyed, then set up again then clearly all profile info, including installed application/registry settings will be lost. Again, its possible to export and then import user profiles, so if the administrator isn't doing this then the question is "why?"

> Do users will have to reinstall client
>   apps they have installed at their
>   workstations at present? I mean, if
>   there is a transition
>   "OldDomain/User1" -> "NewDomain/User1"
>   will folders and registry settings
>   stay appropriate in windows?

As for software installation: If it places settings in the user profile/registry then obviously these will be lost if accounts are newly created with no import. If software is allocated and deployed to machines (or in particular, users) via AD software deployment GPOs then results may be interesting, especially in the case of software published to users. So again, it depends on how the software was deployed and how they're going about re-creating the domain.

**Keep in mind that while I've said things like renaming the domain, exporting and importing accounts, etc. might be possible, there are also perfectly valid reasons why they won't work in certain cases, so that doesn't mean that your admin is doing anything wrong.**

Having said that, in your position I'd want to feel confident that they'd considered the points I mention above and ruled them out, and hadn't simply forgot about them or didn't know how to do them.

Comment: I still would put my bet on administrator incompetence.

Comment: @Tomtom - I know what you mean, that was my first thought, but its impossible to judge that for sure based on the info given.